# Free script to open multiple URLs at once

Tags: php, javascript, url

I am looking for Free PHP script to open multiple URLs at once click. Please let me know if anyone find anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open unlimited url in one page by this HTML code. Try to paste the below code in a html web page.

```
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com" height="50%" width="49%" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com" height="50%" width="49%" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com/m" height="50%" width="49%" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com/m" height="50%" width="49%" ></iframe>
```

CAUTION : google.com and some other sites may not allow to open their site url in a frame.

Comment: This was a great solution for me.  I needed some scripts to run and was able to queue up thousands of IFRAMES in one page without killing the server.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to affect a client's behavior, in which case you don't need PHP. Plain old HTML + Javascript will do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
                window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Open Google and Yahoo</a>
```

Chances are this will be caught by popup blockers though.

To generate such code with PHP, just do:

```
// say your links are in an array:
$links = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com');

$open = '';
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $open .= "window.open('{$link}'); ";
}

echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"{$open}\">Open multiple links</a>";
```

Comment: I will create a page on my site and test your code.  I update the status shortly.   Thanks for your help!    Manim

Comment: Dear NullUserException - Thanks for your script. Actually I am looking for a php script to my website page. Please refer the link: http://golink-directory.com/seo/openurl.php     --- something like this.

Comment: @Manim: You know you can view the source of a webpage, right? The code to do what you want is on the webpage to which you linked.

Comment: Hi Mikey, You are correct but I am not able to view the code, the site is call the actual openurl function from this openurl.php page.